# Chrome Extension > How do I run code on a specific page reload?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

first post and new programmer so apologies in advance. I'm trying to write an extension that I can use in work (I'm a Tester). We use an automated testing package that we make in house and it works with our own custom framework. One of the automated tasks is to'assume date'. I'm looking for an extension where we can do it manually.

The steps to do it manually are

1. Remove everything after the '?' in the url
2. Add a custom setLocalDate&Time url to the end (with the date you need attached)
3. Follow that url
4. Delete everything after the '?' again
5. Go to that url

From looking at examples and following some questions here, I have up to step 3 down (probably really badly, but hey, it does what it's supposed to do). I haven't added anything to custom select the dates yet, that will come later, I just want to get these steps down first.

My problem is, I think I want to add an onUpdate function whenever step 3 is completed. Then I can fill the url with the original url and follow that. I just can't get it to do it though. Here's my content script, the custom url is on line 7. I commented out the on Update function as it wasn't working for me, should I nest it in the first Listener?)

```
// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "clicked_browser_action" ) {
      var firstURL = $("a[href*='g.e']").eq(0).attr("href");
      firstURL = firstURL.substring(0, firstURL.indexOf('?'));
      var newURL = firstURL.concat("?Web.Test.Command=setLocalDate&date=01-07-2017");
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "open_new_tab", "url": newURL});
    }
  }
);

//chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
//  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
//    if( request.message === "date_completed" ) {
//      var newPage = $("a[href*='g.e']").eq(0).attr("href");
//    newPage = newPage.substring(0, newPage.indexOf('?'));
//    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"message": "date_completed", "url": newPage});
//    }
//  }
//);
```

and here's my background script

```
// background.js

// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // Send a message to the active tab
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "clicked_browser_action"});

  });
});

//Receives the message from onMessage
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if( request.message === "open_new_tab" ) {
      chrome.tabs.update({"url": request.url});   
    }
    else if( request.message === "date_completed" ) {
      chrome.tabs.update({"url": request.url});
    }
  }
);

//Receives the message from onUpdated
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "date_completed"});
  });
});
```

Loads of that is probably obsolete. Again, sorry if this doesn't make sense, please let me know if you wnat me to clarify more.

tldr: I would like to go to a specific url when the browser action is clicked and when that page is loaded , to then, and only then to go to another url

Comment: not the answer you are looking for it's way easier to do this in selenium that suffer through a billion layers of chrome extension async messaging

Comment: The code could be indeed simpler, but all you miss is probably checking `changeInfo.status == 'complete'` in [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) callback.

Comment: I appreciate the responses guys. I'll try the changeInfo bit tomorrow. I know there's a million and one better ways to do it but I'm also just experimenting as well. First thing's first, get it working, then I'll move onto tidying it up.